# Laptop doesn't recognize webcamera

Tags: laptop, webcam

I have a Dell laptop with a builtin camera running Ubuntu 20.04. However I want to use an external USB camera in order to get a better image. My laptop doesn't recognize it and it does not appear when I execute *lsusb*. I am sure the camera is OK because it works on my desktop with the same version of Ubuntu. The camera is Logitech C270.

Comment: From a terminal run `uname -r` and see what the output is.  Twice now for me especially with an upgrade to 20.04 it installed the `5.4.0-1025-gcp` kernel that is missing drivers.  The actual kernel that you want is `5.4.0-48-generic`.  The kernel version might be different between both your desktop and laptop.

Comment: My laptop kernel is 5.4.0-40-generic, and desktop 5.4.0-48-generic, This might explain why it works on the desktop. Thanks!

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` on the laptop and see if it tries to upgrade to the `5.4.0-48-generic` kernel.  If it does, make sure to run the `sudo apt autoremove` to remove the older kernels after the upgrade.  It should keep the current kernel and the last kernel, but all others should be removed.